# I can't state up my interface

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, iwlwifi, interface

```
sudo ip link
```

output:

> 2: wlp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
> link/ether 80:c5:f2:81:ca:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

```
sudo ip link set dev wlp1s0
sudo ip link
```

same output:

> 2: wlp1s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
> link/ether 80:c5:f2:81:ca:31 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

I can't state up my interface

Note: I use Debian distribution

Comment: While I use `ip` for ethernet, dummy, and tunnel devices, I tend to rely on my desktop environment (and network manager) for wifi.  Do you have a desktop environment (e.g. gnome, plasma, xfce) installed?

Comment: No, I install Debian with standard system utilities.

Comment: and install just i3wm with xdm and xserver-xorg

Comment: There are tutorials on the internet about [configuring WiFi on the command line](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=linux+wifi+command+line&t=fpas&ia=web). I'd start there.

Comment: For `i3wm` I install `network-manager-gnome` and add `exec --no-startup-id nm-applet` to `~/.config/i3/config`.  That gives me a GUI in the status bar.

Comment: Thanks for your helps! I installed network-manager but dosen't work, after edit this /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf and replaced managed=false with managed=true then restart my service network-manager, this is work perfectly. But yet I don't know how to fixed it. I want know, How can understand?